# How to enable contraints in input field and also display a short message below each input

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am making a website in which user can input `file`, `name`, `estate`, and `description`. I have mandatory all field to **required**. Now i am not able to make a constraint in each `input` and `textform`. I want that if the condition doesn't get fulfilled it should display a text below the form.

AllPost.jsx

```
<div className="form-container">
            <form onSubmit={handleButton} className="form">
              <h2 style={{ fontSize: "30px", fontWeight: 600 }}>
                Start Posting your real estate
              </h2>
              <p
                style={{ fontSize: "20px", fontWeight: 400, letterSpacing: 1 }}
              >
                start adding basic details
              </p>{" "}
              <br />
              <input
                type="file"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setFile(e.target.files[0]);
                }}
                required
              />
              <br /> <br />
              <input
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setName(e.target.value);
                }}
                placeholder="estate"
                required
                min="10"
              />
              {/* <span>estate</span> */}
              <br /> <br />
              <input
                className="textarea"
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setDescription(e.target.value);
                }}
                placeholder="description"
                required
              />
              {/* <span>description</span> */}
              <br /> <br />
              <input
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setEstate(e.target.value);
                }}
                placeholder="name"
                required
              />
              {/* <span>name</span> */}
              <br /> <br />
              <button className="button-3" type="submit">
                Post
              </button>
              {check && <Submitted />}
              {/* <Submitted /> */}
            </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by enabling constraints?

Comment: like word limit to put certain size let say minimum 50 word length allowed

Comment: You can try out validation libraries like yup.